# Exibir o nome do usuario logado pelo email e senha cadastrados no firebase no aplicativo

Tags: android, firebase

Olá, preciso da ajuda de vocês, pois já busquei de varias maneiras e não consigo resolver.
Estou querendo exibir o nome do usuário logado no aplicativo pelo Firebase.
NO Edititext o retorno é essa linha com link para o firebase (.firebaseio.com/usuario/9FrkXtxNuDW97HI0JtrGufquIxQ2/email).

Estou usando o seguinte código na activity:

```
final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuario").child(user_id).child("email");

mEditText.setText(mDatabase.toString());
```

Funciona, mas exibe somente aquela url. O que é que está faltando aí. O Usuário entra na aplicação com o login email/senha do Firebase, e vai para MainActivity, onde executo este comando para exibir o nome. Mas, não parece o nome que está cadastrado no Firebase:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda?

Answer (score 0):

Everlanio para exibir o nome do usuario logado você não precisa buscar os dados no Banco. Você terá que recuperar utilizando o Auth de Login.

[Firebase Auth]: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users?hl=pt-br "

Comment: Bom dia Allef Sousa. Fiz conforme me indicou, mas percebi que ele está exibindo um novo usuário, e não o usuário que foi logado na entrada do app, com a tela de login. a id do usuario  é: "**ZXZlcmxhbmlvQGhvdG1haWwuY29t**". Mas quando entra na main activity a id do usuario que é apresentado é esta: "**9FrkXtxNuDW97HI0JtrGufquIxQ2**". Por isso ele retorna **null**. Como posso fazer para que o usuário logado seja o mesmo do login.

Comment: Eu fiz da seguinte forma, não sei se a mas correta porem a que resolveu para mim. 
Eu so salvo os dados no firebase apos o usuario logar. 
Usuario loga em uma activity , ele é direcionado para a activity principal do projeto onde faco a verificação se esta logado msm.
Caso esteja salvo no Realtime Database.
if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            keyUsuarioLogado = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            userLogado.setIdUsuario(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());                      dataUser.child(keyUsuarioLogado).setValue(userLogado);

Comment: Ok, meu amigo! Obrigado por sua ajuda. consegui resolver.